# Unclear variable syntax in example

Tags: c, variables, pointers

I got this code from a nice book but I don't understand why the variables in the main function are different from the variables in `go_south_east` function and they get treated as the same variables.

```
include <stdio.h>

void go_south_east (int *lat, int *lon)
{
    *lat = *lat - 1;
    *lon = *lon + 1;
}

main()
{
    int latitude = 32;
    int longitude = -64;    
    go_south_east (&latitude, &longitude);
    printf("Avast! Now at: [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longitude);
    return 0;
}
```

To my opinion `latitude` and `lat` are different variables. And the same is for `longitude` and `lon`. Then how can C know that `*lon`, `*lat` are the references of `&longitude`, `&latitude`. To me it should be `lon` in one function and the same `lon` in the second function. Isn't it so?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you pass an address to `lon` and `lat` to the function. The first parameter in the signature is `int *lat`. That corresponds with the first address you passed, in your case, `latitiude`.

Comment: What makes the connection between the go_south_east(&latitude,&longitude) and              go_south_east(int *lat, int *lon)?

Comment: the function go_south_east receives the 2 memory addresses and it doesn't know anything about the outside world

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking the "formal parameters" for the actual values passed in. When a function is defined, you specify the variable type and the local name that you will use within that function. This variable name is completely local to the function and does not have anything to do with what is outside.

```
include <stdio.h>

void go_south_east (int *lat, int *lon)
{
  *lat = *lat - 1;
  *lon = *lon + 1;
}
```

The first variable is pulled off the stack and put in a local variable called lat which is a pointer to an address. It then pulls the second input variable from the stack and puts it into a local variable called lat which is also an integer pointer. The changes are not made to the variables, but to the location in the computer that they point to - a variable location within main.

```
main()
{
  int latitude = 32;
  int longitude = -64;    
  go_south_east (&latitude, &longitude);
  printf("Avast! Now at: [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longitude);
  return 0;
```

}

longitude and latitude are local variables within main and those names are not seen outside the brackets that enclose them. When you call go_south_east, the compiler takes the address of latitude and the address of longitude (which are integer pointers) and puts them on the stack. It then calls go_south_east.  The function does not change the variables it has been given, but gets the address (which is to the variable within main) and changes the contents of that address. That is why the values have been changed when you return.